# React.js Trigger click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to trigger click event in react.js component.

I'm using [rubix](http://rubix23.sketchpixy.com/) template especially  component.
But clicking menu item DropdownButton need to be close but not working.
So I tried to make it manually.

When I click anywhere else menuitem dropdown menu is collapsing.

So I want to trigger click event.

How can I do this?

Here is code snippet for DropdownButton component.

```
<DropdownButton bsStyle='darkgreen45' title={id_str} class='apps_dropdown' key="test" id="sub_nav_btn">
        <SidebarNavItem eventKey="1" name='Application1' onClick={()=>this.handleClick()} href={::this.getPath('application1')} />
        <SidebarNavItem eventKey="2" name='Application2' href={::this.getPath('application2')} />
      </DropdownButton>
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Post the entirety of `SidebarNavItem`. It probably doesn't accept the `onClick` prop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an [outside click handler?](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-onclickoutside) Sounds like you want to fire an event when the user DOESN'T click the DropdownButton?